# Google Struct Data test Tool error:: Missing '}' or object member name

Tags: schema.org

[image]I am deeply under qualified for this stuff, but (Along the lines of getting it right, means .... grabbing a shovel & rolling up your sleeves) I have been looking at all the other schema posts on here and trying to understand the big picture / cloning parts / nudging thing around, but I keep getting an error (Missing '}' or object member name.) after "about" line ? + I have seen (what appears to be) instances of Google green lighting schema, but if it isn't done according to the best practices of accepted standards, somewhere within the magic formula Google seems to ignore / degrade it, so: wandering if packing all of this into one script is the best strategy + How to fix my error.
In all humbleness. Thank you for any help / insight.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
   "@context" : "http://schema.org",
   "@type":"WebSite",
   "name":"Old Bull Lee",
   "url":"https:\/\/www.oldbullshorts.com",
   "about":"The Finest men's Shorts, Shirts & Board shorts",
    }
   {
    "@context" : "http://schema.org/brand",
    "@type":"brand,
    "url":"https:\/\/www.oldbullshorts.com",
    "name":"Old Bull Lee",
    "description":"The Finest Men's Shorts, Shirts & Board shorts. Made In America. Free Shipping.",
    "contactPoint": [{
    "@type": "ContactPoint",
    "telephone": "310-802-0246",
    "email":"info@oldbullshorts.com"
    "contactType": "customer service"
  }]
  "sameAs":[
      "https://www.facebook.com/OldBullLee",
      "https://twitter.com/oldbulllee",
      "https://www.instagram.com/oldbullleeofficial",
      "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Bull_Lee",
      "https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q37855311"
  ]
  "image":"https://www.oldbullshorts.com/pub/media/seller_image/default/Old-Bull-Lee-logo.gif","url":"https://www.oldbullshorts.com"
}
</script>
```

Comment: Is this copy and pasted together? It looks like it is missing a bunch of commas.

Comment: Yes, I copy and pasted it together in note pad (my basic cloning methodology being that a comma goes between each node idea) & then I just swapped out old info for my info.

Comment: Pkus I smashed two different schemas together, which is one of the places where the wheels might have fallin off my wagon.

Comment: You are using two contexts. Check JSON-LD documentation for context https://w3c.github.io/json-ld-syntax/#the-context . You probably need to redefine the structure of your data.

Comment: I'd not class it as a duplicate. there's a lot of mistakes here. I created a working version but can't post it now it been flagged duplicate.